# How to obtain an homogeneous mixture of 10 000 tons of minerals, each one in a different pile?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

I have several (at least six) piles of mineral adding up to 10 000 tons. I want to mix them in one homogeneous big pile. How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Buy a shovel...

Comment: First things first: why do you wan to mix the minerals?

Comment: @SolarMike  Mix one ton,  repeat 10 000 times.

Comment: Second thing: what constitutes "homogeneous" ?  You haven't even stated the range of particle sizes in each source.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you can get some very large motorised “shovels”... :) but it would be a steady job by hand...

Comment: @SolarMike  I agree!  One shovel at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens all the time in the minerals industry where people need to blend material from different stockpiles to produce a supposedly uniform product for a processing plant.

Depending on the size of each stockpile either a front end loader or a bucket wheel excavator are used to take some material from one pile and deposit it elsewhere. You can get fancy and have a number of loader feeding hoppers for conveyor belt and have a number of conveyor belt form one pile.

Depending on what is being optimized: grade of a metal, minimization of contaminant minerals/metals, hardness or softness of the material being fed to crushers/grinders the mix from each stockpile will be varied - such as one bucket from from Pile 1, three from Pile 2 & one from Pile 3. The blend mix will be up to you to decide.